# Page.Profile not saving after user created in a CreateUserWizard

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, asp.net-profiles

I Have the following code which fires `OnCreatedUser` and doesn't throw any errors. `Profile.Title` is getting set to the correct value when inspected after the assignment.

```
public void CreateUserForm_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ddlTitle = (DropDownList)CreateUserWizardStep1.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Title");
    Profile.Title = ddlTitle.SelectedValue;
    Profile.Save();
}
```

However, when I test `Profile.Title` on subsequent pages (the user is definitely logged in) it is `== ""`;

I'm guessing that this is the users old anonymous profile, not the new profile associated with their newly registered user account.

I've tried adding a `Profile_MigrateAnonymous` method (as [suggested here](http://odetocode.com/articles/440.aspx)) to my Global.asax but this code doesn't get hit.

How do I save title to the new users account profile?

**UPDATE**
Here's the code

```
public void CreateUserForm_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var ddlTitle = (DropDownList)CreateUserWizardStep1.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Title");
     var emailTextBox = (TextBox)CreateUserWizardStep1.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("UserName");
     UserProfile profile = (UserProfile)ProfileBase.Create(emailTextBox.Text.Trim());
     profile.Title = ddlTitle.SelectedValue;
     profile.Save();
}
```

Comment: @Greg You're right. Post as an answer and I'll mark as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're correct that the user is still anonymous while that method is called. I'm not familiar with Profile, but I think you need to look the profile up by username instead of relying on the current profile.